# Select random row from table with deleted records

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a table with 3 rows with IDs 1,3,5 because rows with ID 2 and 4 were deleted, how do I make sure I select a row that exists?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($numRows);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

$random = mt_rand(1,$numRows);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT link FROM table WHERE id=$random");
```

This won't ever select row with id 5, and also will select one that doesn't exist (2).

Comment: hard delete or soft delete??

Comment: they're hard deleted, leaving "holes". I understand soft deleting could solve this but is there a way with hard deleting?

Comment: You could use a random offset, based upon a count of the rows.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of rows are small (and you are sure that it will stay that way), you can use `ORDER BY RAND()`
(Please note that this will create performance problems with big tables).

Other way is first counting how many rows are there

> SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table;

then pick a random number

> $rand = rand(1, $total);

and select that row with limit

> SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $rand, 1;

Answer (score 0):

U can use a SQLstatement with **EXISTS**

```
SELECT link
FROM table
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT link
              FROM table
              WHERE id = $random);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a random row and don't care about the id, then you could use:

```
SELECT link FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

For large numbers of rows (10000+), then you may need to implement another solution, as this query can be slow. [This site](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/) has a good explanation and alternative solutions

Answer (score 0):

You could select one, randomly order, like this:

```
SELECT link FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

**UPDATE:**
You should benchmark the different solutions you have, but I'm thinking this one could be nice with large amount of rows:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($numRows);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

$random = mt_rand(1,$numRows);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT link FROM table WHERE id>=$random LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($link);
if(!$link){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT link FROM table WHERE id<$random LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($link);
}
```

Comment: with lots of rows that becomes inefficient doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow your approach then you have to do some changes in your query.

```
1.) Query one : select id from table. // It will give you array of existing id.

2.) You have to use array_rand(). and use your second query.
```

**Example :**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT ID FROM table");
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$random = array_rand(array_flip($result), 1);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT link FROM table WHERE id=$random");
```